# JQuery: delegate and datepicker

Tags: jquery

I need that every text input in a given class is a datepicker. Something like:

```
$("input[type=text].time").datepicker();
```

but I'm adding a lot of code via Jquery.load() so I believe I need a delegate. The problem is I don't know how to do it, because as far as I know, load event cannot be used in a delegate. It will be easy if it exists:

```
$(document).delegate("input[type=text].time", "load", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I don't see the need for a delegate.... that just confuses the reader.

Comment: If you load via AJAX a page that contains a new input of that class ("time"), without using a delegate it's not automatic the datapicker activation. I load a lot of data vía jquery.load() and it's not only the datapicker class, there are more like this that need to be set by hand on each page load.

Comment: If you're loading the content, add the datepicker on `success`. I haven't found a good alternative to the way you're wanting to use `.load()`.

Comment: If the code is injected via an Ajax request, just initiate datepicker() as a callback event.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$("body").delegate("input[type=text].time", "focusin", function(){
   $(this).datepicker();
});
```

I used delegate on the body because I don't know if you have your code in other containers that you can target.

Here is a fiddle that targets a specific `div` with delegate:

http://jsfiddle.net/MpqAy/

Comment: So on every click, try to add a date picker to any valid result?

Comment: It's not what I was looking for exactly, but it works.. I don't know what happens when you reinitialize a lot of times datepicker

Comment: @jk that's great. Thanks for posting this. It's just what I was looking for and works perfectly - first time.

Comment: +1, @JaredFarrish I had the same concern. Luckily, it would appear jQueryUI does not rebind if it has already bound: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#LC189

Comment: Good idea. But why not just *focus* instead of *focusin*?

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric Depends on your need. _This is distinct from the focus event in that it supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling)._ http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

Comment: What if this opration is to be done after a certain div finishes loading its content ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is relatively old but I just wanted to share my solution as it's still relevant in 2018.

```
 $('#container').off().on('focusin', '.date', function () => {
     $(this).datepicker();
 });
```

If you're using jQuery with TypeScript

```
 $('#container').off().on('focusin', '.date', (e) => {
     $(e.currentTarget).datepicker();
 });
```

You'll notice the `off()` function here. This will wipe out events from the Jquery object in question. So you won't get any bubbling issues. Keep in mind though, that it kills **all events** on that object and not just the event you're running again.

I wouldn't recommend using `off()` or `on()` on document, html, or body level jQuery objects. Just my opinion though.