# DatePicker not working inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, modal-dialog

I have a site and [here is a link](http://pastebin.com/WHHMnh3S), When you click on textfield you can see the DatePicker working
But iF you click on I`mportFriend -> Add Manual Friend ->` then if you click on birthday field the datepicker never appears.I can see through firebug that the field got the `hasDatePicker` attribute.
I am not sure what making it not to show the datepicker,anyone who can help me please thanks

Comment: look into event delegation...

Comment: why do you wrap it in a $(function() ?

Comment: @SmithSmithy - technically, he doesn't need that, because his script is at the end of the body.  But it's good practice to put your script inside of a document ready function like that.

Comment: @Bluetoft thank you but the answer is bit vague

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @Bluetoft says, the answer is event delegation.

The reason it's not working for you is because your datepicker is being bound to elements *that exist at the time the script is run* (not to mention, the birthday field has a different id than #datepicker, which is what your script is binding to).

When you dynamically bring in the new form, the datepicker is not bound to the new elements.

So, one method, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313723/870729), is to construct your script like so:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").delegate("#datepicker", "focusin", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

**Additionally**, your form "birthday" input has an id of #fi_bday, which is another reason it's not being bound.  I'd recommend that you assign any inputs where you want the datepicker with a class of "datepicker", then change your script to bind the datepicker functionality to `'.datepicker'` elements:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").delegate(".datepicker", "focusin", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

**Finally**, if you don't want to utilize the better, generic class method above, you can use two selectors in the selector below.  The method below delegates in a manner as to bind the datepicker to the modal window element(s) as well:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").delegate("#datepicker, #fi_bday", "focusin", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 17):

The solution mentioned above did not work for me.

**As date-picker has not the z-index property, so it was not showing on modal/popup which has the z-index.**
I found that the date-picker was working fine but it was showing behind the modal.So I added the z-index property to date-picker class.

```
.datepicker{ z-index:99999 !important; }
```

That's why I am sharing my solution to other users. I am sure this will help someone.

Comment: thanks, @t4taurus, I am facing this issue and am finally able to sort it out with your help.

Comment: II am having one select drop down field and one date picker field - Both are in  diff div row .If i gave like this ,If I select drop down , then date picker is showing over the field

Answer (score 2):

Add property container:

```
$('.datepickerClass').datepicker({
           ...,
            container: "#modalId",
           ...,
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add z-index to your datepicker class and add important with it. give a Greater value than modal. Normally modal have a z-index of 1050

```
.yourDatePicker{ z-index:9999!important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

about C#.net
in .aspx

```
function getjqueryselect() {
        $("#<%=this.txtBeginEdit.ClientID%>").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["th"]);
        $("#<%=this.txtBeginEdit.ClientID%>").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        $("#<%=this.txtEndEdit.ClientID%>").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["th"]);
        $("#<%=this.txtEndEdit.ClientID%>").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    }
```

and then in Page_Load in aspx.cs

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "test", "getjqueryselect();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I figured out that I was rendering the datetimepicker library twice (once in the main page and once in the partial view). Rendering only once in the main page solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the event delegation snippet/z-index But the select year dropdown funcionality of jquery datepicker just did NOT work - i can select date/month but NOT year

While date-picker for bootstrap did work - the gijgo one or the tempusdominus (which i did NOT try) - I just wanted to stick to jquery

So i got rid of modal functionality - and used collapse in bootstrap to show/hide/div as well as custom div_onshown/hide/cancel/ok using javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="notifymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

remove your tabindex="-1" in your modal it will work