# Change month and year not working in bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

In my project i am using jquery datepicker.It works well in all pages but it's not working in bootstrap modal window.Below is my code for loading datepicker.

```
  $("#StartDate").datepicker({
                                changeMonth : true,
                                changeYear : true,
                                dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
                            });
```

Now, I cannot able to change month and year from datepicker dropdown.
How to fix this issue?Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: may I ask if your modal dom create dynamically using jquery? or it was existed already before you call the datepicker ?

Comment: it was already existed.

Comment: are there any error message in console ?  and can u provide your modal related code?
https://jsfiddle.net/u8jf9se7/1/
i have created a jsfiddle example, and it works using datepicker on bootstrap modal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing jQuery DatePicker in Bootstrap modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059598/implementing-jquery-datepicker-in-bootstrap-modal)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While searching more on it, I found [it is already answered in another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21088713/1064325). Here is some working code, taken from there:

```
var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

Why aren't you using bootstrap datepicker?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the modal already exists, then you can try event delegation as mentioned in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519994/datepicker-not-working-inside-a-modal).

```
$(function() {
   $("body").delegate("#StartDate", "focusin", function(){
      $(this).datepicker();
   });
});
```

One more thing you can try is increasing the z-index of the StartDate text box

```
#StartDate {
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely work. I made a fiddle with jquery ui datepicker in the modal window. check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/kr20nu8n/2/

html:

```
<button id="openModalButton">open modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <input placeholder="click for datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
});

$("#openModalButton").click(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

Maybe if you could post your full code, we could find the error that causes this.

Comment: It's not working in mozilla.but working fine in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd" data-date-autoClose="true"/>
```

Try this. It works fine in Chrome.By the way,I'm using the bootstarp datepicker!